# OpenERP 6.1 : Domain,Context from Python Method

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have a created an extra column in res_users and i want to filter all my further views based on that field for the user logged in. I am new to this and couldn't find how filter my view based on a database column. If i use a static value in `<field name="domain">[('test_id','=',6)]</field>` it works but how to fetch it from the res_users table.
Here is my code. Thanks

```
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">test.type</field> 
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="domain">[('test_id','=',context.get('example'))]</field>
```

Python Method i have tried is :

```
    def _get_test(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    if context is None:
    context = {}
    res = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context)
    view_id = res.test_id and res.test_id.id or False
    context['example'] = view_id
    return context
```

Comment: did you tried to pass value to default_get() ?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, i didnt pass it in default_get() . Could you specify where i should write that. Thanks